# delete and modify comments by users

Tags: django

i've added to my Blog post comments now the problem is that i'm trying to create remove function for that and i have one but now eve uset thak is logged in can remove all the comments how can i fix this that user can delete only their own comments??
the funnyiest thing is that i have this function on my posts and it wokres and if i'm trying to do the same on my comments then i've get 404 error. Ive tried a few different ways but nothing worked You are my only hope:)

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required





# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})


@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post-detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

**Models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**post_detail**

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user_posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"d F, Y" }}</small>
                {% if object.author == user %}
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <hr>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
     {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="date">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}">remove</a>
                </div>
                 <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong> {{ comment.created_on|date:"d F, Y G:i" }}
                 <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %} 
    {% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make author in Comment model Foreign Key(User). Then in views check this condition:

```
if comment.author == request.user:
  comment.delete()
```

Comment: Hey it worked but i had to remove all my dbsqlfile cuz i was unable to do migration but now it works TY

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote and mark it as correct answer.